# MPI pgm image blurring implementation

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I need to write an MPI code which blurs a pgm image.
The kernel type and size are specified in the command line.
Here's the problem: each process should receive a portion of the image (i.e. height/num_processes rows) to blur. However, for blurring it will also need information on the pixels surrounding its portion (because the kernel will exit the portion boundaries above and below).

I am faced with two options:

1. Process 0 reads the whole image and scatters it to all other processes.
   Each process sends its top k/2 rows (where k is the kernel size, an odd number) and bottom k/2 rows to its previous and next rank process (rank 0 and rank (num_processes-1) only send the bottom and top rows respectively).
   Now all processes have the portion to blur, plus two strips of k/2 rows above and below.
   Each process can blur its portion, then the root gathers everything.
2. Every process reads the whole image, then creates a smaller copy, which includes the portion it's supposed to blur, as well as the k/2 rows above and below.
   Each process has all information necessary to blur its assigned portion.
   After blurring, we need to "cut" the portions so they don't overlap anymore, and the root can then gather the blurred portions.

I have made the first implementation work. Then I thought about the second option, which seems more straightforward to implement, and potentially more efficient. Is this true?
I kind of think this should be a no-brainer, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Option 1 is not the right idea. Scattering from one process is a time and memory bottleneck.  In Option 2 you would let each process read the whole file, but only retain the part they need. That's a properly distributed way of working.

Comment: Either option will end up with data, in memory, representing the pixels of the blurred image.  What then?  Display the image?  Write back to disk?  And while @VictorEijkhout's criticism of your option 1 is valid, it's a frequently-used 'architecture' for MPI programs, especially so when the costs of initial data distribution can be amortised over the duration of a lengthy iterative computation.  And then there is option 2b, where each process reads only its own part of the file ...

Comment: You don't write anything about your system. Does it have a parallel file system (such as Lustre)? If yes, reading a corresponding file part by each process with MPI-I/O is likely the best option.

Comment: Do you have to use processes? I would rather go for multi-threading and sharing the memory of the original image as sketched in option b), however without the need to read it completely per process.
If it has to be processes you can still skip/seek to the first required line for your valid convolutions.

Comment: I think OP has been set a problem to solve as part of an introductory course in programming with MPI, for which any reasonable solution is a 'valid' solution in the sense that OP will learn much from implementing it, indeed OP might learn much from implementing all the solutions proposed.  In production code an image would have to be humongous to warrant decomposition across multiple processes for a simple one-step blur operation. And for multiple images, well that's embarrassingly parallelisable so doesn't need the complexities of MPI either.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the aim is to write the blurred image to a file. Indeed using MPI for this task is feeling like overkill, considering how simple the OpenMP version (also required in my assignment) was to code in comparison.
The idea of each process reading only its own part of the file seems like the best way to go in my case, I will get to work on that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I would list your options and its pros and cons.

**Option 1:**

*Pros:* Easy to implement

*Cons:* Won't scale well (if you want to blur multiple images in future -extend the algorithm). i.e., if you load all images into one process and then try to redistribute it there are obvious issue associated with memory and communication.

*Usecase:* If you know the size of the image is not an issue to keep it in-memory always and the data distribution overhead is less compared to the time needed for blurring and reaggregating the image, then go with it. But this is not the ideal way.

**Option 2:**

*Pros:* Easy to implement, Communication overhead is reduced coompared to option 1.

*Cons:* Again won't scale (if you want to use 100s of images in the future). All processes will have the replica of the image in-memory.

*Usage:* You are not concerned with the in-memory usage by storing the image in all processes, why not :) But this is also not an ideal way.

I would recommend another **option 3** where **each process reads the part of the file using *MPI-IO*** and works on it's data and at the end, writes the results into the file in parallel using ***MPI-IO***. This is the ideal way.

*Pros:* Scales, saves lot of memory. If you have very large image (say, something from NASA), then potential memory issues caused by option 1 and option 2 can be avoided.

*Cons:* Implementation effort is high, if there are no parallel file system, there will be bottleneck with reading the image. Still it will be better than option 1 and 2.

Comment: I have never heard of MPI-IO. Shouldn't this be more or less the same as modifying my `read_pgm` function so that each process skips irrelevant pixel values and only saves the relevant ones?

Comment: Yes, exactly. As you mentioned in option 2, instead of all process reading the same file, they read part of the file in parallel with the help of special IO API provided by the MPI. You can read more about [MPI-IO here](https://events.prace-ri.eu/event/176/contributions/59/attachments/170/326/Advanced_MPI_II.pdf).